# Converting large CSV(10GB) to excel files

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, etl, google-cloud-run

Currently working on a process to convert a large csv to specified formats (.txt, .xls, xlsx).

This process will run in a docker container in GCP Cloud Run w/ 8C and 32GB mem

I've tried the dataframe libraries (pandas, dask), that have an method for outputting to different file formats, but they just take forever(around 3000sec.).

Are dataframe libraries just not built for these tasks? Not doing any analytical work on these files, just converting them.

Comment: Don't use special libraries (e.g., pandas). Just open the file and process one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe libraries may more inefficient than a specific tool for conversion since they are designed to read the data into memory and operate on the data efficiently rather than just transforming it from one file to another.

There are some specific open source tools that are designed for rapid conversion of files which may be better suited for this type of work https://github.com/mentax/csv2xlsx.

However, if the dataset is large the amount of I/O required to read the data from disk can be a bottleneck. You can try out other disk types as well https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance

Comment: Thank you for the input, the only concern that I had was having to convert that csv to an excel file with multiple sheets(due to the max row constraint) but I’ll definitely look out for more cli tools as well